# AWS SAM Environment variable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sam

i was wondering if someone can help me here. I am devleoping a python SAM application in which i need to use environment variables.
at the moment i am declaring my variables in template.yaml

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    Environment:
      Variables:
        FMPREPKEY: <myfmprepkey>
```

However, given my project is on github, i'd rather put a placeholder in the yaml and 'override' the value somehow at runtime
How can i do that?

Kind regards
Marco

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are fixed and predefined at config. What you're looking for is basically invoking the lambda with your variables passed in as InvokeInput object, and then make use of this data inside your application.

example from AWS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/python_3_lambda_code_examples.html):

```
response = self.lambda_client.invoke(
    FunctionName=function_name,
    Payload=json.dumps(function_params)
)
```

Your function_params would be an object that you'd dynamically set and pass into the function at runtime. Then you can access that object inside lambda by referring to the event object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i see.. thanks. Although, if instead of using a SAM app i create a normal function, then i can set the environment variables in the Configuration section of the Function...

Comment: Yes but that would mean re-deployment of the function, and your environment variable would not be set "at runtime" as you want it. if you want a variable parameter at runtime, you'll have to support it via event, or store somewhere else, maybe in SSM or a database.